# Hosting win form controls in WPF window

Tags: wpf, winforms, textbox, windowsformshost

I am trying to host win forms control in WPF using bottom tag, when I compile my application the control get created but they are invisible, I can click and type but I can't see the textbox or the content. Any suggestions?

```
<WindowsFormsHost Opacity=".75" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="32" Margin="5">
    <Forms:TextBox x:Name="textbox"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Comment: did you call `textBox.Show()`?

Comment: nevermind! I found out that I was setting Allow Transparency to true, which was causing the win form host to be transparent as well as the content in it :)